# Calculate the mean,min and max of every 15 rows in data frame

Tags: r, max, each, mean, min

I have a data frame with 77 columns and 1080 row df
I want to reduce my data so, i want for every column: to find the min, max and mean of every 15 rows.
For example, for the 1st column i want for every 15 rows to find min, max , mean, for the second column the same and so on and on for all the 77 columns,  and put all these into a dataframe. How can i do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

We can create a grouping variable with `gl` and then do apply the functions with `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(group = as.integer(gl(n(), 15, n()))) %>% 
   summarise_all(funs(min, max, mean))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 35 * 10, replace = TRUE), nrow = 35))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R and apply functions:

```
# dummy data from akrun
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(77*1080, 0, 1), ncol = 77))

# Vectors with means, mins, and maxes for each row
means <- apply(df1, 1, mean)
mins  <- apply(df1, 1, min)
maxs  <- apply(df1, 1, max)

# Make to a data frame
df2 <- data.frame(means[seq(1, 1080, 15)], mins[seq(1, 1080, 15)], maxs[seq(1, 1080, 15)])
```

Or without creating additional objects (the vectors means, mins, and maxs) just  go directly into a data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame("Mean" = apply(df1, 1, mean)[seq(1, 1080, 15)], "Min" = apply(df1, 1, min)[seq(1, 1080, 15)], "Max" = apply(df1, 1, max)[seq(1, 1080, 15)])
```

And to reduce computation time, reduce the dataframe first:

```
df1 <- df1[seq(1, 1080, 15),]
df2 <- data.frame("Mean" = apply(df1, 1, mean), "Min" = apply(df1, 1, min), "Max" = apply(df1, 1, max))
```

Comment: this seems really useful, but i think i didnt say correctly what i wanted to do. For every column, i want: every 15 rows to find the min, max, mean! Thanks for your answer!